# Flutter/Android - Monitoring not working after app is killed

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

Expected behavior
I should receive a post request to my api when the device detects ble beacons. I receive the request correctly when the app is opened, but when it is killed, I don't receive the call.

Actual behavior
I don't receive any request.

Mobile device model and OS version
Google pixel 5, Android 13

```
class CustomApplication : FlutterApplication() {
companion object {
private const val TAG = "CustomApplication"
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    //Works here, i receive the call on my api properly
    //sendRequest() 
    Log.d(TAG, "App started up")
     val beaconManager: BeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
     val region = Region("FetchVision", null, null, null)
     beaconManager.getRegionViewModel(region).regionState.observeForever(monitoringObserver)
     beaconManager.startMonitoring(region)
}

private val monitoringObserver = Observer<Int> { state ->
    if (state == MonitorNotifier.INSIDE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call")
        //Doesn't work when app is killed, but works when is open
        sendRequest()
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No beacons detected")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So, you're expecting your app to keep working `after` its process was terminated? You would need to implement a service for that: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: Im trying to implement "Starting an App in the Background" from https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html but it doesn't seem to work